# Возможно ли в ASP.Net core сделать динамическое переключение между partialview?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Предположим у меня есть 3 кнопки под номерами 1, 2 и 3. Возможно ли сделать так чтобы при нажатии на эти кнопки подгружалось содержимое из partial views? Т.е. при нажатии на кнопку 1 в окне Preview появлялось содержимое _1.cshtml, при нажатии на кнопку 2 в окне Preview появлялось содержимое _2.cshtml и т.д.
[image]

Comment: Без проблем да возможно. Ajax вам в помощь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57087333/5045688

Answer (score 0):

AJAX (асинхронный JavaScript и XML) — это средство загрузки данных с сервера без перезагрузки страницы. Он использует функциональность встроенного в браузер XMLHttpRequest (XHR), чтобы сделать запрос к серверу, а затем обработать полученные от сервера данные

Comment: Это скорее комментарий, чем полноценный ответ.